# Java HashMap Filtering

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have a hashmap data say

```
{1={Context=Legacy, Owner=Ram, Number=xyz}, 2={Context=Legacy, Owner=Ram,
 Number=xxx}, 3={Context=Legacy, Owner=Sri, Number=xrt}}
```

How do I filter out this Hashmap which has maps that contains  `Owner=Ram`

Expected Result:

```
{1={Context=Legacy, Owner=Ram, Number=xyz}, 2={Context=Legacy, Owner=Ram, Number=xxx}}
```

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: I checked quickly on google, you can see a version of filtering before and after java 8:
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Comment: Have got my query answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using java8 or later.

```
// If you have setup like this
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> m = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> c1 = new HashMap<>();
c1.put("Context", "Legacy");
c1.put("Owner", "Ram");
c1.put("Number", "xyz");
m.put(1, c1);
Map<String, String> c2 = new HashMap<>();
c2.put("Context", "Legacy");
c2.put("Owner", "NotRam");
c2.put("Number", "xyz");
m.put(2, c2);

// you can do like this.
Map result = m.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .anyMatch(y -> y.getKey().equals("Owner") && y.getValue().equals("Ram")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Really helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Java 8 then you can achieve that by using the [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) and [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Map<Integer, MyCustomObject> map = ...;
map.values().removeIf(o -> !o.getOwner().equals("Ram"));
```

---

For pre Java 8 you may achieve the same using an `Iterator`:

```
Map<Integer, MyCustomObject> map = ...;
for(Iterator<MyCustomObject> iter = map.values().iterator(); iter.next();){
    if(!iter.next().getOwner().equals("Ram")){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Which both will remove every entry that has `Owner != Ram`.